# MacBook Pro (A1990) dead - How to diagnose if battery or mainboard issue?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, battery, charging, motherboard

Hi everyone & thanks for your help in advance!

My MacBook Pro (A1990) won‘t start (no reaction at all) after I haven‘t used it for a couple of weeks.

Is there any possibility to check via multimeter or other tools if the reason is the battery (repairable) or the motherboard (financially not reasonable to repair)?

**Things I have tried to narrow down the cause of error to either battery or motherboard:**

I tried all the keyboard combinations for different types of reset.
I also tried different chargers.

Open it up and disconnected & reconnected the battery (one „block“ looks a little bloated“).

Also bought a USB-C diagnosis tool and it doesn’t charge at all (no current, voltage ok), no matter which port is connected (and same thing when I had the battery disconnected).

Thanks a again and looking forward to your replies :)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the motherboard might be broken?

Comment: No (apart from frequent usage at max. Capacity of CPU & GPU and therefore high temperature), however battery and motherboard were the most common hardware issues for dead MacBooks from this series when I googled around.

Comment: I'd plug in charging cable to determine if it's battery issue. If it's related to battery, it'd start, since Macbook would get powered by cable. If it won't, then most likely it's MoBo.

Comment: @Skye-AT since I did that, I can safely say it’s not a battery issue? That would mean MoBo and therefore not financially sensible to repair.

Comment: @Mitch I would say so? Not certainly, but most likely.